# Basic html-mapping or url-rewriting for google appengine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-rewriting, url-routing, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite urls for a static site on Google Appengine. 
I only want 
http://www.abc.com/about for http://www.abc.com/about.html 
I don't need rewriting for stuff like abc.com/page?=1 or anything.
I just wanna figure out how to explicity rewrite urls for html pages.

The code I'm currently using (which isn't working) -

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class PostHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
        template_values = {}
        post_list =  { 
            'home' : 'index.html',
            'portfolio' : 'portfolio.html',            
            'contact' : 'contact.html',
            'about' : 'about.html'
        }

        if slug in post_list:
            self.response.out.write('Slugs not handled by C-Dan yet')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('no post with this slug')

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),('/(.*)', PostHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Isn't working how? What happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your constructor, you want:

```
def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/portfolio/', Portfolio),
    ('/contact/', Contant),
    ('/about/', About)
    ])
  util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

This mean anytime someone goes to http://www.abc.com/about/, they will be 'routed' to your About handler.

Then you have to make an About handler.

```
class About(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(template.render('about.html', None))
```

I'm not familiar with your coding style, but what I've shown you has worked for me in all my projects.

Comment: Don't put the application definition in main - put it outside it. That way, it's only defined once, and you can easily convert your app to work on the Python 2.7 runtime. Also, the indentation in your first snippet is wrong.

Comment: how would you go about putting the application definition outside the main??
fixed the indentation problem, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot mrmo123, worked like a charm!  @nick, I'm using 2.7, how to go about putting the application definition outside the main? thanks

Comment: no problem! something to keep in mind: if you want http://www.abc.com/about/123 or http://www.abc.com/about/foo to route to about.html, just change `('/about/', About)` to `('/about/.*', About)`. you get the idea.

Comment: @mrmo123 yeah, I started working with python just 2 days back. Needed a jumpstart (a basic, working piece of code) which I can build upon, got it! :D